# Make responsive image

Tags: image, height, width, responsive-images

/*How to set width and height of image to be 150px and to be responsive*/

/*HTML*/

```
<div class="tabs__tab-image-container"> 
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1208234904405757953/mT0cFOVQ_400x400.jpg" class="tabs__tab-content-img">
</div>
```

/*CSS*/

```
.tabs__tab-image-container {
        max-width: 150px;
        min-height: 150px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    tabs__tab-content-img {
        border-radius: 50%;
        max-width: 150px;
        height: auto;
        display: block;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be clearer in your question.  You want an image to ALWAYS be 150px square but the DIV to be responsive? Or do you want the IMAGE to be responsive within the DIV?  As you're only showing a DIV with a single image in it, it's hard to tell what the goal is.

A responsive page is one that changes based on the viewport size; locking the image down to a fixed size kinda defeats the purpose in that case.   Your CSS also isn't using the image class as it's incorrectly formatted.

The following fixes the image class as you've specified it, but all this does is round the image corners; the content won't be responsive:

CSS:

```
.tabs__tab-image-container {
    max-width: 150px;
    min-height: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
 }

 .tabs__tab-content img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    max-width: 150px;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="tabs__tab-image-container"> 
  <div class="tabs__tab-content"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1208234904405757953/mT0cFOVQ_400x400.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

To make the page responsive, you can add viewports in CSS for different page sizes, or if it's just the image displaying (with a line of text in the div for example) use the following:

CSS:

```
.tabs__tab-image-container {
    text-align:center;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
    font-size: 10.0vw;
    font-weight:700;
  }
.tabs__tab-content img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100%;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="tabs__tab-image-container">
  <div class="tabs__tab-content"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1208234904405757953/mT0cFOVQ_400x400.jpg">
Text Here
  </div>
</div>
```

If you only need the image, you don't even need the tabs__tab-image-container class, just use the tab content class targeting the image.

Comment: I need to set an image max width and max height to 150px, but also this should be the default value of width and height.  And it should work with any, original size, image.